# How to capture repeating groups in Regex (for C#)

Tags: regex, grouping, repeat

I've to detect and extract from a string a repeating group of characters and list one part of each captured group.

Here is an example of string to parse: "za e e**Start**Good1**End**ds q**Start**Good2**End**sds df"

My Regex is: "`.*?(?::Start(.+)End.*?)+`"

Expecting groups captured expected: `Good1`, `Good2`, `etc`

My Regex capture is wrong: it seems that `(?::Start(.+)` is considered as group to capture...

May I miss something?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you just need `Start(.*?)End`. No idea what your input really looks like. Have you got actual asterisks there or is it formatting?

Comment: Hi Wiktor no astericks...Only for bold font.

Comment: So, use my regex with `Regex.Matches`.

Comment: I tell you: use my regex. `Regex.Matches(input, @"Start(.*?)End").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`

Comment: Wiktor, i need a complete Regex syntax to be used in my project. I can't use Link. And this question has no duplicate as far as I know: I need to extract these values several times.

Comment: Sorry, the way you described the issue, it is a duplicate. Please explain what you need and why you need that, especially why you can't use C# code.

Comment: Wiktor, in my case, I use a general method to call all my regex and I didn't want to add special analyze in that case. And the main difference with potential duplicate is that I need to get ALL instances between Start and End, not only one or first one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex do the job :

```
/(?<=Start)(.+?)(?=End)/g
```

Comment: Thanks @baddger, I tried this regex ((?<=Start)(.+?)(?=End))*  (without ** for bold font) and i get all characters one by one like this: "z", "a", " ", "e", etc ... Other idea?

Comment: try the updated answer :p

Comment: Yes, I'm closer now... :) Just need to hide start and end groups... Your regex returns "za e eStart", "Good1", "Endds dqStart", "Good2", "Endsds df". But thanks for this simple syntax with <= and =. I tried to hide them but no return with this one: "(?:<=Start)(.+?)(?:=End)"

Comment: Ok, simpler than I thought. You were right Baddger. Regex is: "Start(.+?)End". No need to define a repeating group to get all instances...

Comment: so Wiktor Stribiżew say the good answers :p

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this pattern: `\*{2}Start\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}End\*{2}`

For this input string: `za e e**Start**Good1**End**ds dq**Start**Good2**End**sds df`, it captures `Good1` and `Good2`.

You can play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/dG0dX6/2

Comment: Sorry Andrew, you were right too...